# Using QGIS to convert from WGS to UTM not working

Tags: qgis, wgs84, contour, utm

My predicament is this. I have inherited a bunch of data in multiple projections, and I need to calculate hub distance to get distance from one grid of points to a contour layer (I have extracted vertices for this layer so it is just distance points-points).

The first layer when looking in the metadata is in WGS84 - pretty standard. The other grid of points is in UTM (GDA 94, 55 G).

The confusion is this:

When I open both files in a single workspace with no specified projection (the projection in lower right is listed as NO PROJECTION, with a bunch of extra code afterwards), I can see both files and they are more or less arranged how I would have assumed. However, this means when I calculate hub distance I get degrees - I need kilometres.

[image: Example of everything displaying as expected]

SO, I try to save the contour file that is in WGS84 in GDA94. This works fine, but if I open a new workspace and set project CRS to GDA94 and open the grids, I see them where expected at the coordinates I expects, however when opening the contour file it becomes flipped and distorted, and placed thousands of kilometres from where is was when I had them open in default CRS - presumably projected on the fly. My question is this - if they both look normal before I export them... What am I doing wrong for the contour points to be so drastically warped and moved??

[image: Resulting files saved in GDA - note extremely warped contour compared with before (and yes thats backwards Australia!]

Comment: The first screenshot shows an error about `EPSG:4938`, wich is a geocentric system. Are you sure that your layers have their data defined in geographic and UTM projected systems, and that the CRS of the layers is the same that corresponds with their data? Also, try to always show the QGIS bottom bar in the screenshot, so we can see the CRS of the map canvas that you are showing.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, that is the kick up the butt to reassess I needed... For anyone other newbies looking at this in the future I had mixed up the Geocentric projection option GDA94 (EPSG:4938) with the CRS projection GDA94, 55G (EPSG:28355). Choosing the CRS projection fixed my problem.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. If you wanted to add the same comment in an answer and accept it, it would be visible to future users and the question would be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer courtesy of Gabriel De Luca (see comments on original post)

"The first screenshot shows an error about EPSG:4938, wich is a geocentric system. Are you sure that your layers have their data defined in geographic and UTM projected systems, and that the CRS of the layers is the same that corresponds with their data? Also, try to always show the QGIS bottom bar in the screenshot, so we can see the CRS of the map canvas that you are showing."